# Right limit of integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Following is the joint PDF of RV $X,Y$ and $Z$
$$f(x, y, z) =\begin{cases}
 kxy^2z;&  0 < x,y < 1, 0 < z < 2,\\
0,& \text{elsewhere}. 
\end{cases}.$$

To find value of $k$ I tried to integrate it from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ for all three variables and set it equal to one. But as I took the upper limit of $x$ and lower limit of $y$ as $\infty$ no result found. I guess I am missing something here. Please help me.

Comment: "I guess I am missing something here." Indeed, you are "missing" that the conditions $0 < x,y < 1$, $0 < z < 2$, are a crucial part of the definition of the PDF.

Comment: Are you also aware that $~0<x{,}y<1~$ is (indeed confusingly) often used as shortened for $~0<x<1 \,,\, 0<y<1~$ ?

Comment: oops i got confused that it is 0<x, y <1 means x from zero to infinity and y is less than 1 so negative infinity to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that $[0<x{,}y<1]$ is (indeed confusingly) often used as a shortened notation for $[0<x<1],[ 0<y<1]$ ?   Thus your pdf is likely intended to be: $$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)=\begin{cases} k x y^2 z & : [0\leq x\leq 1], [0\leq y\leq 1], [0\leq z\leq 2] \\[1ex] 0 & :\textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Taking the upper limit of $x$ as $1$, and the lower limit of $y$ as $0$ will give you a definite integral that actually converges.

Answer (score 0):

The Compact Support of $f$ is $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,2]$ , we have
$$\iiint\limits_{{{R}^{3}}}{f(x,y,z)dxdydz=\,\,k\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{x{{y}^{2}}z\,dxdydz}}}}=1$$
thus
$$\frac{k}{2}\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{0}^{1}{{{y}^{2}}z\,dydz}}=\frac{k}{6}\int_{0}^{2}{z\,dz}=\frac{k}{3}=1\Rightarrow \,k=3$$